# Symfony2 API Key Authentication - No route found for

Tags: php, symfony

I followed the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html), and this is how my code is organized:

src/Company/AuthBundle/Security/ApiKeyAuthenticator.php
src/Company/AuthBundle/Security/ApiKeyUserProvider.php

*(they are the same as sample classes in doc)*

```
# File: services.yml

apikey_authenticator:
   class:  Company\AuthBundle\Security\ApiKeyAuthenticator
   public: false    

# File: security.yml

  firewalls: 
    api:
      pattern: ^/api
      stateless: false
      simple_preauth:
      authenticator: apikey_authenticator
      provider: fos_userbundle
      security: false
      anonymous: true
```

And now, If I try to access e.g. http://symfony-project.dev/api?apikey=somekey, I got the following error:

> No route found for "GET /api"

Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is fairly clear really - you haven't defined a route for a `GET` request for `'/api'`.

The security component you've configured takes care of authentication and granting access, but it does not control any logic specific to your application. You must create a controller and a route for requests like this.

You can see your currently defined routes with `$ php app/console debug:router` - if you've tried to define a route, that will help you debug it. If not, [you must create one](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html).